# Recover an SVN repository with multiple missing revs/ files

Tags: svn, backup, recovery, rebuild

I'm trying to recover an SVN repository after a hard drive failure. Unfortunately, the backup will not help as it was out of date.

From 7,797 revisions, **we lost only the following seven (7) files** from the .../repo_dir/db/revs/7/ directory:

7437 (7-9 Dec 2009) (file also missing from revprops/ dir)

7461 (16 Dec 2009)

7519, 7520, 7521 (8 Jan 2010)

7679 (19 Mar 2010)

7683 (19 Mar 2010)

This single SVN repository contains many different software projects/products. **So I would prefer to be able to rebuild my repository and only lose the revisions that explicitly depend on those seven missing revs/ files,** rather than having everything stop at rev. 7436. **Fortunately, those particular seven revisions are for trivial projects.** Losing their recent revisions would not be a big deal. Recovering the repository for all the revisions which don't depend on those seven revs/ files would be excellent.

Is there a way to do this?

P.S. Other files may also be missing from the revprops/ dir, not just 7437 -- If I'm willing to lose commit messages, can I live without some revprops/ files?

Comment: Has anyone else run into this situation? How did you handle it?

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to use `svndumpfilter`:

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.reposadmin.maint.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.filtering